# Let $f: X^{n} \to Y^{n}$ smooth function with $X$ compact $n$-manifold. Show that the set of regular value is open and dense in $Y$.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f: X^{n} \to Y^{n}$ smooth function with $X$ compact $n$-manifold, $Y$ $n$-dimensional manifold.  Show that the set of regular value is open and dense in $Y$.

Let $\mathcal{R}$ the set of regular value. By Sard's Theorem, $\mathcal{R}$ is dense. The hard part is to show that $\mathcal{R}$ is open.

Some hint? Thank you.

Comment: The critical points in $X$ are closed...

Comment: $\mathcal{R}$ is in $Y$

Comment: Right, but the image of the critical points in $Y$ are...

Comment: Let $C$ the set of critical points in $X$. Why is $f(C)$ closed?

Comment: @Alladin That's because $f$ is a closed map since $X^n$ is compact.